# Django translation escape % sign

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm trying to translate some text that contains a percent sign like so:

`{% trans "100% butterfly" %}`

When I run the makemessages command, I get the following output in my german .po file:

```
#: .\appName\templates\appName\butterflies.html:54
#, fuzzy, python-format
#| msgid ""
#| "100% butterfly"
msgid ""
"100%% butterfly"
msgstr ""
"100% shmetterling"
```

Which when compiled, fails to translate the text to German. I've tried doing `{% trans "100%% butterfly" %}`, but this causes the pages to display "100%% butterfly" when viewed in both german and english. I've also tried using blocktrans tags instead to translate the text, with the same result.

Manually erasing the extra % in the .po file, along with the `#, fuzzy, python-format` line works, but I'd rather not have to do this for every % sign I'm trying to translate.

How do I escape this in my HTML so that Django stops generating a fuzzy translation in the .po file and doesn't get confused thinking I'm trying to do some python formatting?

Comment: Looks like doing `{% trans "100&#37; butterfly" %}` does the trick, but might be confusing for the translators.

Comment: Did you try using `"100%% shmetterling"` in the .po file for the msgstr?

Comment: Just now, yes. I get "100%% shmetterling" as the rendered html output

Comment: There's a related ticket [#24257](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24257), which is fixed in the upcoming Django 1.9. The creator of that ticket said they used blocktrans as a work around, but I see you already tried that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24257#comment:2) in Django's Trac, adding a translator comment to deactivate python format above the string that you want to translate can fix / workaround this issue.

If the text to translate is in your Python code, use:

```
# Translator: xgettext:no-python-format
_('100% butterfly')
```

For `trans` template tag, you can try:

```
{# Translators: xgettext:no-python-format #}
{% trans "100% butterfly" %}
```

as [explained in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#comments-for-translators-in-templates).

Comment: In Javascript, I successfully used // Translators: xgettext:no-c-format

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way is to use the html code : `&#37;`

It is the most elegant way for dealing with django translation for example.

Comment: That's true for developers, but again, is confusing for translators who don't understand the html code

Comment: Yes, but sadly, you cannot do it with django javascript translation. ```&#37;``` and warning your translators is the best way today.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a Django problem with a fix possibly coming in Django 1.9.
One workaround is to do:

`{% blocktrans with percent="%" %}100{{percent}} butterfly{% endblocktrans %}`

Which essentially embraces the python formatting it thinks you're trying to do when you put a % symbol in your trans text. It's verbose and sucks, but it works.